# Nivo Slider and Google Analytics

Tags: jquery, drupal, google-analytics, nivo-slider

I'm running an ISP redirect site which sole purpose is advertisement space for local businesses. The site is running the Nivo Slider and has google analytics. We have everything setup how we want but we are trying to figure out how to track the image views that scroll on the nivo slider. As in the number of times the picture was seen or displayed within the browser. We are not looking for click or outbound links. We already have that covered. Anyone know ho to do this or where to begin?

Comment: are you tracking the # of times image x is viewed by visitor y? Or how many times x is viwed by all (including on page rotations)?

Comment: Trying to get how many times x is viewed by all. I'd imagine the end result would show me an image name and how many times it was displayed on the page.

Comment: why not keep track of the images each time they are displayed server side? Don't you already do that by pushing the image into the slider?  Or are you concerned that even in the slider it doesn't get shown in time.

Comment: Here is the site/one of the properties: http://welcometonwfl.com/content/watercolor  If I go to it right now and sit on there for 5 min....How many times are the pictures displayed within that 5 minutes....That is what I'm trying to record

Comment: @jakub I don't want to tell my customer here is an analytics account and go here to view these other reports...Also the script doesn't subtract...its would just add view counts. When an operator removed the ad the count would still show there....I'm thinking my best bet is a custom drupal module with google analytics api embedded? +drupal on tag